# Is there a way of converting a url to a pdf with puppeteer-core under 50mb?

Tags: node.js, npm, puppeteer

I want to convert a URL to a PDF using puppeteer-core on a server. I tried using the 'chrome-aws-lambda' package which lets you do just that, but this only works on lambda. And puppeteer is much bigger than 50mb. Is there a package to accomplish this using puppeteer-core and a browser that fits under 50mb?

Requirements

- No APIs
- Under 50mb
- No templates
- Give it a URL, get back a pdf

Any help appreciated

Comment: I don't think this answer is relevant. I'm talking about package size, not how much resources I'm using on the server. Also, I'm not actually using Lambda. I'm just looking for something that is small and lightweight that is less than 50mb

Comment: Exactly, it's difficult to find a browser under that amount. Firefox is close but not quite. I was hoping someone knows about a cut down version of firefox or of something else

Comment: There are many serverless functions services such as aws-lambda, and in my case, I am using a node environment provided by bubble.io where we do not have unlimited control and access to the hardware. The question is really clear - I am looking for a browser that could be used with puppeteer-core under 50mb. I am already aware of cmd> curl remote url.pdf but in my and many users cases we don't have access to this. See the chrome-aws-lambda package.

Comment: I see, but it's a start! May I have the name of the browser?

Comment: Ah! That sucks. I wonder how chrome for aws lamda package achieves this ...